# How to limit the memory consumed by a Gurobi integer program

Tags: gurobi

I was wondering if there is a way to restrict the maximum amount of memory that can be used by Gurobi while it solves the MIP using branch and bound.

I have a 16GB machine but I would like Gurobi to only use 4GB of RAM and if it exceeds that, I would like for it to stop performing branch and price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to limit memory use by Gurobi, and I'm not aware of a similar feature for another solver. Operating systems generally have ways to limit memory use by a particular process, but exceeding the limit typically kills the entire process.

There are various ways to reduce memory use in Gurobi MIP; a few key ideas are:

1. Set Presolve=2
2. Set Method=1 or 2 (to avoid concurrent LP)
3. Set NodefileStart to a small value like 0.5 or 1.0

However, these may increase solve time.

Comment: I think you are right. I probably have to create a container and run gurobi on it.

Answer (score 1):

There are, in fact, two ways how to limit the memory used by Gurobi.

1. [MemLimit](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/10.0/refman/memlimit.html) parameter 
   A hard limit that will result in an exception after reached, and the solution will not be accessible.
2. [SoftMemLimit](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/10.0/refman/softmemlimit.html) parameter 
   Softer limit that will result in a MEM_LIMIT status code, and the optimization will terminate gracefully. Check out the status codes [here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/10.0/refman/optimization_status_codes.html#sec:StatusCodes).

In Python, you can set the soft one very easily, in your case probably like this:

```py
import gurobipy as gb

model = gb.Model()
model.params.SoftMemLimit = 4 # The limits work in GB
...
```

For the hard limit, it is a little bit more difficult. You need to set it to an environment, for example like this:

```py
import gurobipy as gb

with gb.Env() as env:
    env.setParam("MemLimit", 4)
    model = gb.Model(env=env)
    ...
```